# Core Data Fetch Request Bug

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have an app I am building using Core Data. I have an inital load of all the `Biking` Structs using a `Fetched Results Controller`. I am then trying to just send a request to check for a specific `Biking` Struct using a fetch request but I am getting the error: `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the predicate line. I am just needing this request to check if a struct with a specific `ID` is saved or not. I am new to all this so forgive my ignorance! What am I doing wrong?

```
private let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
private let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
private var fetchedRC: NSFetchedResultsController<Biking>!

private func refresh() {
    do {
        let request = Biking.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Biking>
        if query.isEmpty {
            request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bikingOwner == %@", note)

            let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Biking.buttonText), ascending: true)
            request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
            do {
                fetchedRC = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
                fetchedRC.delegate = self
                try fetchedRC.performFetch()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

var bikingQuery = [Biking]()

var query = "test"

let fetchRequest = Biking.fetchRequest() as NSFetchRequest<Biking>
// ERROR Below
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "buttonID == %@", query)
do {
    bikingQuery = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
} catch {
    fatalError("Failed to fetch: \(error)")
}

if bikingQuery.count >= 0 {
    print("Found!")
}
```

Comment: Hi @PrashantTukadiya Just changed those suggestions. The bug is still there...

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Button ID. Am I suppose to have a different context for each request? The first is using a Fetched Results Controller but the second is just a request...

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya It's a Double...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your predicate line

```
 let query = "test"
 fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "buttonID == %@", query)`
```

with

```
let query:Double = 2.0 // Any Value you want to search

fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "buttonID == %f", query)
```

For more info see this link

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Hope it is helpful